# getting error Exception thrown: read access violation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nodes

I am currently working with an array of Node pointers. I want to make a node at that index (aBet[]) if that index of that Node array is pointing to null. However I get an **error on the **if statement** that says: ****"Exception thrown: read access violation.**
Node was 0x1110112."**

I also made a default constructor to make the values in the array point to Null:

```
Lib::Lib()
{
    // establishes an empty node
    Node* r = new Node;
   for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LETTERS; i++)
   {
    root->aBet[i] = nullptr;
   }
```

}

```
struct Node {
    Node* aBet[MAX_LETTERS];
 };
```

I have also created a node as well.

```
Node* ode;
int charPos;
ode = r;

for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) 
{
    charPos = (int)word[i] - (int)'a'; 
    
    if (ode->aBet[charPos] == nullptr) // an error is here**
    {
        Node* newBranch = new Node;
```

Why do I keep getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not initialize *currNode* so `currNode->aBet` has an undefined behavior

[edit after remarks]

Your definitions are strange, for me *aBet* must be an attribute of *Dict* rather than of *Node*, also currently *Node* is quite useless because *only* memorize pointers to *Node*

If you just want to memorize words you just need to define the class *Dict*, for instance :

```
class Dict {
   private:
     std::list<std::string> aBet[MAX_LETTERS];
   ...
};
```

if you want to also have a definition for each word :

```
class Word {
  private:
    std::string name;
    std::string definition;
  ...
};

class Dict {
   private:
     std::list<Word> aBet[MAX_LETTERS];
   ...
};
```

you do not have to manage the list by hand, we are not in C, better use features from *std*

note your *Dict* can be replaced by a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` where each key is a word and the value its definition ;-)

Comment: @scorpiquarius note to do `Node* currNode = new Node;` will not initialize `currNode->aBet` array content too ;-) Add a constructor to *Node*

Comment: I have a default constructor that makes the pointers in the index become null. But I am assuming it might not be working then

Comment: the default constructor of *Node* doesn't initialize *aBet*, you have to write an explicit constructor to fill *aBet* with null pointers

Comment: Alright so I'd have to go through the Node array and fill it with pointers?

Comment: So then I'd take the loop and put it in the Node constructor

Comment: @scorpiquarius yes, and remove the allocation in constructor of *Dict* because it creates a memory leak (the allocated node is lost), very probably *Dict* has a member being pointer to node and you need to initialized that pointer with nullptr or with `new Node`  or that attribute is not a pointer to, difficult to know how you use it

Comment: @scorpiquarius in fact for me it is strange *aBet* is an attribute of *Node* for me it must be an attribute of *Dict*

Comment: Ahh yes! I know, I am currently doing this as I have to implement a word and each letter of that word is a different node. So it basically makes a path of letter pointers of nodes.

Comment: @scorpiquarius  I edited my answer, please read it, I use *list* for the list of words starting with the same letter, useless to manage the list by hand